# SWIFT. Вопросы общего характера от начинающего

Tags: ios, swift, framework, navigationcontroller

1. Если у меня в приложении все держится на show контроллеров, то это значит при работе приложения у меня один вью на другой накладывается и создается бесконечное количество отображений VC одновременно? К примеру две кнопки в двух контроллерах, одна показывает один VC, другая - другой

   Если да -  вытекает вопрос: надо использовать этот метод для перехода между контроллерами?

   navigationController?.pushViewController(<#T##viewController: UIViewController##UIViewController#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>
2. Прошу прощения за столь обобщенные вопросы, но не могу разобраться с некоторыми моментами.

   Что нужно сделать в коде  "подсоединить аутлет с вю в свойство ячейки"  foregroundView - это значение фреймворка, [ссылка](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FoldingCell) с Readme , пункт второй

   **Connect the outlet from this view to the cell property   *foregroundView*.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если у меня в приложении все держится на show контроллеров, то это значит при работе приложения у меня один вью на другой накладывается и создается бесконечное количество отображений VC одновременно? К примеру две кнопки в двух контроллерах, одна показывает один VC, другая - другой

Да все правильно, только учтите что все контроллеры добавляются в стек (грубо говоря цепочку) 1контроллер->2->3->4 
navigationController?.pushViewController - добавляет новый контроллер в стек и показывает его на экране, для возврата на предыдущие экраны используются другие методы например

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: Bool)
```

Подробнее можно найти [тут](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

> Что нужно сделать в коде "подсоединить аутлет с вю в свойство ячейки"  foregroundView - это значение фреймворка, ссылка с Readme , пункт второй

В сториборде открываете ваш контроллер с ячейкой, создаете констрейнт для высоты ячейки, потом жмете (дальше пример подключения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше справа в меню выбираете вкладку 1 и зажимаете + на 2 (найдете там нужный аутлет) и с зажатой кнопкой перетягиваете на левое меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и с зажатой кнопкой перетягиваете на левое меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после в правом меню будет вот так выглядеть (аутлет подключен)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такое детальное объяснение, без Вас бы не разобрался :)